# Is there an inequality that involves $\|x+y\|$ and $\|x\|\|y\|$?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

I was working on a problem where I had reached a step $$c^2\|x+y\|+ 2 \varepsilon \|T\|^2 \|x\|\|y\|$$
This made me curious and I just wanted to know if there were any inequalities in general that involved $\|x+y\|$ and $\|x\|\|y\|$ that I didn't know about?

The only one I've been able to come up with so far is
\begin{align*}
(\|x+y\|)^2 &\leq (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2\\
&= \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\|x\|\|y\|
\end{align*}

But I wanted to know if there's something more interesting.

Comment: Are you talking about "norms?"

Comment: Although there are many, you could have a look at [this](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/cis515-11-sl4.pdf)

Comment: Yes, norm of a vector (I suppose I am in particular referring to the Euclidean norm). Also, unfortunately, I don't see any inequality of relevance in the PDF you shared. Nevertheless, thank you so much for sharing it!

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment, but umm not exactly :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a norm induced by an inner product like the Euclidean norm, you have

$$\| x + y \|^2 = \| x \|^2 + \| y \|^2 + 2 \cos(\theta) \| x \| \| y \|$$

so the only universal inequality you can apply here is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality which is just $-1 \leq \cos(\theta) \leq 1$ in this notation.